# Contar tamanho de número em Go

Tags: algoritmo, golang

Tenho uma variável `int`, preciso saber quantas casa ela tem e capturar o número referente a cada casa, por exemplo meu numero é `57890`, preciso que retorne a quantidade de casa desse número, `57890 = 5`. Também preciso do número que está presente em cada posição posição `3 = 8`.

Comment: Você pegou um exemplo ambíguo. Poderia dizer quem seria o número índice 0? E o índice 1?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

O jeito mais fácil é converter com [`Itoa()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) para texto e pegar os caracteres com [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len). Mas dá para fazer matematicamente também (módulo [`math`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/)).

```
package main
import ("fmt"
        "strconv"
        "math")

func main() {
    t := strconv.Itoa(57890)
    fmt.Println("Tamanho matematicamente calculado:", math.Floor(math.Log10(math.Abs((57890)))) + 1)
    for i := 0; i < len(t); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%c\n", t[i])
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cRLrRk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eovvtzdv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Go/NumberLength.go).

Peguei o elemento 2 porque o índice começa em 0, então o terceiro é o número 2.

Note que não é necessário fazer conversões já que só haverá caracteres ASCII.

Comment: Falta responder a parte sobre o número no índice 3

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado verdade, tava com pressa, fiz agora. Aproveitei e fiz matematicamente também, agora tá como ele pediu na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Para o primeiro caso use o método [`strconv`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/).[`Itoa()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) para converter o valor numérico para *string* e o método [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) para verificar o tamanho da mesma. Para a segunda situação, use [`rune(str)[position]`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#rune) no qual, `position` representa a posição da *string* passada como parâmetro. Lembrando que você disse posição `3`, no entanto como o vetor inicia com `0`, o retorno em relação a posição `3` seria `9`. Veja:

```
package main
import ("fmt"
        "strconv")

func main() {
    str := strconv.Itoa(57890)
    fmt.Println(len(str))

    // index inicia com 0. então 2 representa a posição 3
    fmt.Println(string([]rune(str)[0])) // saida 5
    fmt.Println(string([]rune(str)[1])) // saida 7
    fmt.Println(string([]rune(str)[2])) // saida 8
}
```

Veja [funfando no play golang](https://play.golang.org/p/raCYphlaYv).